# Replace values in a matrix in R subsetting from vectors

Tags: r

I want to replace values in a matrix based on matrix indexes stored in two vectors (one for x, another one for y). I did it some time ago but forgot the syntax for subsetting based on vectors.

Let's say i have this matrix and these 2 arrays:

```
m <- matrix(0,10,10)
x <- c(1,3,5)
y <- c(2,4,6)
```

And i need to replace m[1,2], m[3,4], m[5,6] with other value, what would be the syntax in this case? I tried m[x,y] but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Without sparse matrix support:
If we include `z <- c(4.5,5.6,6.7)` for the values then,

```
for(i in 1:length(z)) m[x[i],y[i]] <- z[i]
```

If you want to an apply solution, this is all I could think of,

```
apply(data.frame(x=x,y=y,z=z),1,function(row) .GlobalEnv$m[row[1],row[2]] <- row[3])
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid that due to being very lazy-computing, luckily, i remembered how it was, the answer is m[cbind(a,b)] to subset based on vector indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I remembered how it was, to subset a matrix from vectors the syntax is:

```
m[cbind(x,y)]
```